# Rebus INFO messages appearing in Marketing Automation webjob console log output

Tags: marketing-automation

I am running `Marketing Automation 9.1.1` in `Azure PaaS`, scaled topology. The MA engine is running fine but I am only recently seeing some new INFO messages in the WebJobs console output when new enrolments are processed in a plan.

Any ideas where this might be coming from and why? (The plans are sending emails via EXM, which might explain the Rebus connection). Is there perhaps an output log level that has been set too low?

```
[12/03/2019 10:03:58 > fdf166: INFO] Rebus.SqlServer.DbConnectionProvider INFO (Thread #14): Supplied connection string will be modified to enable MARS
[12/03/2019 10:03:58 > fdf166: INFO] Rebus.SqlServer.Transport.SqlServerTransport INFO (Thread #14): Database already contains a table named "[dbo].[Sitecore_Transport]" - will not create anything
[12/03/2019 10:03:58 > fdf166: INFO] Rebus.Routing.TypeBased.TypeBasedRouter INFO (Thread #14): Mapped Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Model.Messaging.AutomatedMessage -> "AutomatedMessagesQueue"
[12/03/2019 10:03:58 > fdf166: INFO] Rebus.Threading.TaskParallelLibrary.TplAsyncTask INFO (Thread #14): Starting periodic task "CleanupTrackedErrors" with interval 00:01:00
[12/03/2019 10:03:58 > fdf166: INFO] Rebus.Bus.RebusBus INFO (Thread #14): Starting bus 1
[12/03/2019 10:03:58 > fdf166: INFO] Rebus.Bus.RebusBus INFO (Thread #14): Started
[12/03/2019 10:03:58 > fdf166: INFO] Rebus.Pipeline.Send.SendOutgoingMessageStep DEBUG (Thread #14): Sending Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Model.Messaging.AutomatedMessage -> "AutomatedMessagesQueue"
[12/03/2019 10:07:24 > fdf166: INFO] Rebus.Pipeline.Send.SendOutgoingMessageStep DEBUG (Thread #14): Sending Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Model.Messaging.AutomatedMessage -> "AutomatedMessagesQueue"
```

Comment: These log entries are category INFO. That's why you are seeing them. Higher the level to DEBUG or ERROR and they should be gone...

Comment: I checked [engineroot]\App_data\config\sitecore\CoreServices\sc.Serilog.xml and it's set to minimum level=Warning as default. Not sure if I am looking at the right setting in the right place.

Comment: before suggesting anything on this particular error. I will ask question that have you applied hotfix from Sitecore for Messaging (SC Hotfix 325852-2 Sitecore.Messaging 2.0.1) as this resolved most of the issues. This hotfix has dll with name Sitecore.Framework.Messaging.Rebus.dll which controls this and this hotfix has to be deployed to all app service. Idea to suggest this is it will fix your DTU issues which you might haven't checked and because high DTU operations you will get so many log entries. After applying this let me know if your getting entries then can suggest further.

Comment: Further going to support my above comment few of these log info coming from https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.SqlServer/blob/master/Rebus.SqlServer/SqlServer/DbConnectionProvider.cs this cs file. Which is basically a part of Rebus DLLs So I will suggest to apply this patch if still you get this info log then you can conclude that this is part of the code from Rebus and as mentioned by @PeterProcházka you can chagne level to warning or error and then it will go away.

Comment: Thank you I will explore the hotfix applicability to our scenario.

Comment: @andyp  , just to confirm you are modifying the loglevel in the config of the webjob (rather than the app service?).  Should be in [serviceroot]\App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data\Config\sitecore\CoreServices\sc.Serilog.xml

Comment: yes, that seemed to make no difference.